# Need to include some results from NOT IN

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a SQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6222/1 that needs a little help.

I need to return any group_id where there is a user_id which doesn't have the 'GROUP' setting  **within that group_id**.  My query in the SQL fiddle is cutting out 13565 as it has 'GROUP' in a different group_id.

It's got to be simple but I just can't get it.

```
CREATE table role(
  role_id int,
  role_type varchar(255),
  group_id int,
  user_id int
);

INSERT INTO role VALUES(71002,'Group',1465,8301);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(71000,'Training_admin',1465,7959);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(71003,'Training_admin',1465,8301);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(71001,'Training_User',1465,7959);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(71004,'Training_User',1465,8301);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(71005,'Training_User',1465,13541);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(493513,'Initial',6314,13565);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(493522,'Ongoing',6314,13565);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(493534,'Initial',3128,13565);
INSERT INTO role VALUES(493556,'Group',3128,13565);

select * from role 
where user_id not in (select role.user_id 
    from role
    where role.role_type = 'GROUP')
```

Comment: you should include your code here in your question

Comment: @GordonLinoff - here you go...:)

Comment: Didn't you already asked this question??

Comment: @JoëlSalamin - Yes, I asked **a** question but it turns out it wasn't the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, this allows for multiple predicates:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Role AS r
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    role AS r2
            WHERE   r2.user_id = r.user_id
            AND     r2.group_id = r.group_id
            AND     r2.role_type = 'GROUP'
        );
```

That being said, [MySQL performs better using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` over `NOT EXISTS`](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), so you should probably rewrite as:

```
SELECT  r.*
FROM    Role AS r
        LEFT JOIN role AS r2
            ON r2.user_id = r.user_id
            AND r2.group_id = r.group_id
            AND r2.role_type = 'GROUP'
WHERE   r2.role_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for that!!  The "SELECT 1" is new to me, I think that's why I always try to use NOT IN,

Comment: @DrDan Even if the `SELECT 1` is new to you, go for the second solution without the subquery. It's a good practice to avoid as much as possible the use of subqueries in your SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're looking for without subquery (for better performance):

```
SELECT *
FROM role R
LEFT OUTER JOIN role R2 ON R2.user_id = R.user_id
                          AND R2.role_type = 'GROUP'
WHERE R2.user_id IS NULL
```

Hope this will help you.